# I have some instances of a class and I pushed them into an array. Can I loop through the array and update the price of all the array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop

I have a parent constructor like this:

```
let list = [];
class Pictures {
    constructor(price, title) {
        this.price = price;
        this.title = title;
        list.push(this)
    }
    updatePrice(price_increase) {
        this.price = this.price * price_increase / 100 + this.price
        return this.price
    }
}
```

I also have two child classes that inherit from the Pictures(Parent) class

```
class Photograph extends Pictures {
    constructor(photographer, camera, aperture, contrast, price, title) {
        super(price, title);
        this.price = price;
        this.title = this.title;
        this.photographer = photographer;
        this.camera = camera;
        this.aperture = aperture;
        this.contrast = contrast;
    }
    alterContrast(new_contrast) {
        this.contrast = new_contrast;
    }
    toString() {
        return `Photographer: ${this.photographer}, Camera: ${this.camera},
         Aperture: ${this.aperture}, Contrast: ${this.contrast}`;
    }
}
```

And:

```
class Painting extends Pictures {
    constructor(artist, type, owner, title, price) {
        super(price, title);
        this.price = price;
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.type = type;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    printProvenance() {

    }
    toString() {
        return `Artist: ${this.artist}, Type: ${this.type}, Owner: ${this.owner}`;
    }
}
```

And these are the instances of the classes

```
let photo_one = new Photograph('Kyle', 'Nikon', 32, 21, 30, 'Sunset')

let photo_two = new Photograph("Maya", "Sony XPR", 100, 23, 100.00, "Festival of Color");
```

I pushed all of the instances to the "list" array in the parent constructor. Is it possible to loop through the array and use the `updatePrice` method in the `Pictures` class to update the price value of all objects?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you show us what ````list```` looks like?

Comment: No worries I got an answer, I had to use the forEach loop list.forEach((element) => { 
    element.updatePrice(5)
})

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, just use .map , .forEach or for loop

```
    list.map((item) => {
        item.updatePrice(1000)
    })
```

But I can recommend to store 'list' inside class.

Comment: Yes, the forEach worked. Thank you